# Unable to load an .xnb file due to a wrong platform value

Tags: c#, monogame, windows-10

I have some trouble using the Monogame content pipeline under windows 10. Note this is the first time me using Monogame.

```
model = Content.Load<Model>("cube");
```

Everything builds successfully and it seems to be in the correct place but there is a problem with the .xnb itself.

I have traced the exception to this location

```
if (x != 'X' || n != 'N' || b != 'B' ||
    !(targetPlatformIdentifiers.Contains((char)platform)))
{
    throw new ContentLoadException("Asset does not appear to be a valid XNB file. Did you process your content for Windows?");
}
```

The problem is that `platform` has the value 103 which is a `g`

```
static List<char> targetPlatformIdentifiers = new List<char>()
{
    'w', // Windows (DirectX)
    'x', // Xbox360
    'm', // WindowsPhone
    'i', // iOS
    'a', // Android
    'd', // DesktopGL
    'X', // MacOSX
    'W', // WindowsStoreApp
    'n', // NativeClient
    'u', // Ouya
    'p', // PlayStationMobile
    'M', // WindowsPhone8
    'r', // RaspberryPi
    'P', // PlayStation4

    // Old WindowsGL and Linux platform chars
    'w',
    'l',
};
```

I have downloaded Monogame from Github and added the `WindowsGL` version to my project.

I have tried Windows, WindowsGL and Linux as a platform in the content pipeline and it always resulted in the platform to be `103`.

Answer (score 0):

I made a mistake, I cloned the most recent version of Monogame but I should have used `checkout` to switch to version `v3.4`.